# Disable a Key Entirely Temporarily with Corresponding Button Java

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a program that, put in short, advances upon the pressing of a button. During certain execution phases the button is temporarily deactivated to prevent it from firing in code at the wrong point in time. I have now created some Key Bindings to act as shortcuts for the pressing of the buttons, but need to disable them during the same aforementioned times, or else they will cause my array to be trashed and wiped before I even use it.

Any tips, methods, or Java methods I can use to [very] easily but a hold via disablement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the bound key press the JButton with `doClick()`. Then when the button needs to be deactivated, call `setEnabled(false)` on the button.

As an aside, I suppose your button and key binding could share the same action, but I don't know if calling `setEnabled(false)` on the Action will prevent the key from running the Action's actionPerformed method. Time to test.... Be right back...

---

Edit: yep you can just have the JButton and the bound key share the same Action that is enabled/disabled:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestBoundAbstractActions {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final MyAction myAction = new MyAction();
      final JButton actionButton = new JButton(myAction);

      JRadioButton enableRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Enabled", true);
      enableRadioButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

         @Override
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            myAction.setEnabled(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
         }
      });


      JPanel panel = new JPanel();

      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      String mKey = "m key";
      panel.getInputMap(condition).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_M, 0), mKey);
      panel.getActionMap().put(mKey, myAction);

      panel.add(new JLabel("Press \"m\" to activate key-bound action"));          
      panel.add(actionButton);
      panel.add(enableRadioButton);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}

class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
   public MyAction() {
      super("My Action");
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_M);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      System.out.println("boo!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice investigation! I will use this knowledge and of course give you one of the special thanks boxes - most of the grade will know your name (yay...). Thanks again. But I have one final question - if it should be its own let me know: If I wanted to, at the end of the program, make the right arrow, for example, revert to its original function of moving the cursor and not actually activating a button, what would I put in the code for the AbstractAction's actionPerformed, is there a revert to default? If this need be its own question just say so.

Comment: @WilliamBrun: probably it should be a new question because it is a new and unrelated problem. That, and because I don't know the answer right off the bat.

Comment: Great! I hope you answer it

Comment: Ah nevermind - the limit of 6 is reached - But I am eternally grateful for your help and that of this community